# Error handling in a loop using unzip -t and mail

Tags: bash, error-handling, unzip

I have a series of programs that upload compressed zip files to our server for backing up purpose.
I run the following command daily to check the Zips are okay (As they are only backups in case of failure)

```
find . -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip -t '{}' ';'
```

Instead of running this daily, i wanted to setup a scrip that would run daily and notify me if there is any failures in the unzip integrity test.

For example

```
for i in $(find /SOMEDIR/Backups/ -name \*.Zip); do
if  unzip -t "$i" | grep -q 'End-of-central-directory signature not found'; then
  echo "File is currupted"
  # Add in a Mail Trigger to send email
fi
done
```

How can i capture the whole error that has occurred and send it in a email, i tried adding a `| mail -s "Some Message" "Emailaddress@Email.com"` at the end of my grep

the outputted error

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /SOMEDIR/Backups/test/Currupted.Zip or
        /SOMEDIR/Backups/test/Currupted.Zip.zip, and cannot find /SOMEDIR/Backups/test/Currupted.Zip.ZIP, period.
File is currupted
```

I am interested in the Error and the Directory as there are multiple directory's for different backups, any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Here is a working version for anyone interested, i feel this is more of a fudge, if someone wants to comment on a cleaner way i am always willing to learn.

```
for i in $(find /SOMEDIR/Backups/ -name \*.Zip); do
    if unzip -t "$i" | grep -A 5 'End-of-central-directory signature not found' > test.log; then
        echo "$(cat test.log)" | mail -s "Backup Zip Test Failed" someemail@someone.co.uk
    fi
done
```

Comment: The `-q` throws away the message you are interested in, so you better remove it. I would also add a `-A 4` or so (depending on how many lines you want to output. However  I am surprised that your script does correctly detect the error, because I would have expected that `unzip` prints its error messages to stderr.

Comment: So how would i alter this to use the stderr instead of the output?

Comment: Throw away stdout, and redirect stderr to the new stdout (`2>&1 1>/dev/null)`. However you claimed in your question, that your code **did** work, but simply does not return enough information, so I don't understand why you are interested in changing this part.

Comment: I am not one for it just works, i like to know more and understand why one method is better than other, running versions side by side while throwing multiple scenarios into the equation to see how each handle. 
But your right it works, i just outputted the IF line to a log file, and then Cat the log file to the mail body. It give me what i want. not a very clean method but it works.
Updated post with changes